# chewie flutter can't play video from youtube

Tags: flutter

I try to play video from youtube but I can't play

```
final controler =
            new VideoPlayerController.network("https://youtu.be/0vQWv_EKN6g");
        if (!widget.is_audioArea) {
          controler.setVolume(0.0);
        }
        final chewieController = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: controler,
          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          autoPlay: true,
          looping: true,
          showControls: false,
        );
```

Comment: Check this one, it might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66409512/11217945